# Provided bucket: version00-d20e4.appspot.com does not match the Storage bucket of the current instance error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have tableview that contain image I retrieve image from Storage by URL I store it database but occasionally I get this error :

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Provided bucket: version00-d20e4.appspot.com does not match the Storage bucket of the current instance: myprojectname-d2551.appspot.com'

(I got this image in another view using collectionview so I am sure I use right GoogleService-Info.plist)
last time I get this error I delete all related node form database and all my storage, add it again then its work. 
what is wrong happen? 
My code to re

```
    if let ProductImageURL = product.ProductImageURL{
        let imageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL:ProductImageURL)
        imageStorageRef.getData(maxSize: 2*1024*1024, completion:{ [weak self](data,error)in
            if  error != nil {
                print(error)
            }else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.ProductImage?.image = UIImage(data:data!)
                }
            }
        })//.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [NSInvalidArgumentException](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsinvalidargumentexception) exception is thrown when you pass an invalid argument to a method.

The value you are passing to the variable “ProductImageURL” is “myprojectname-d2551.appspot.com”. However, it was expected to be “version00-d20e4.appspot.com” instead. Make sure that the you are using the correct path in the “ProductImageURL”.

You may try hard coding the value of “ProductImageURL” and see the results.